# Iterate an array using two or more elements at a time

Tags: javascript, lodash

In short I was wondering if there was a way to do this in a more straight forward way. The problem with chunk I feel is I got to create a new array then I have to map it so I get just the first value. Is there a way I can loop 2 items at a time?

```
a = [5, 1, 6, 0, 8, 0, 9, 1, 10, 0]
b = _.chunk(a, 2)
zeros = b.filter(s=> s[1] == 0).map(s=>s[0])
ones = b.filter(s=> s[1] == 1).map(s=>s[0])
```

Alternative I'd like

```
zeros=[]
ones=[]
_.MyEach(a, 2, (l, m)=> if(m==0) zero.push(l); else ones.push(l))
```

OR (less likely but acceptable)

```
zeros = _.MyFilter(a, 2, (l, m) => if(m==0) l else null);
ones  = _.MyFilter(a, 2, (l, m) => if(m==1) l else null);
```

Comment: sometimes you just gotta code the algorithm directly...  p.s. IMHO this question is poorly written given your rep - the problem statement is written in code using a library that not everyone's familiar with whereas a trivial English explanation of the requirements would have been clearer.

Comment: ES6 one liner - needs golfing - `var [zeroes, ones] = a.reduce((p, c, i, a) => { if (i % 2) { p[a[i]].push(a[i - 1]) } return p }, [[], []])`

Comment: Seems more a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or: `[zeroes,ones] = a.reduce((r, v, i, a) => i%2 ? (r[v].push(a[i-1]),r) : r, [[],[]])`

Comment: @trincot yeah, I just came up with exactly that - `var [zeroes, ones] = a.reduce((p, c, i, a) => i % 2 ? (p[c].push(a[i - 1]), p) : p, [[], []])`

Comment: @Alnitak: Are you sure? If you tried explaining this without code you'll use vastly more words OR confuse someone. Also a large percentage of JS developers are familiar with underscore or lodash

Comment: @acidzombie24  perhaps, but it took a little while to discern what your actual problem was.  For a description - "for every odd element in the array, if its zero place it in one result array otherwise place it in another result array"

Comment: @Alnitak: Yeah that's what I wanted. But it in no way mentioned what I didn't want. Answers could have easily have been what I wrote in my original code. I just realized I didn't need chunk/lodash if I wrote an ugly ass loop but I like clear code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without the `_` library altogether, in this case using ES6 syntax which allows decomposing the 2D array into individual variables in one hit:

```
var [zeroes, ones] = a.reduce(
    (p, c, i, a) => i % 2 ? (p[c].push(a[i - 1]), p) : p, [[], []]);
```

This iterates over the array once, and for the odd elements it looks at the zero or one contained therein, and drops the preceding value into either the `[0]` or `[1]` element of the seed array.

Comment: Wow I did not expect to see the comma operator in JS. Well done.

Comment: Also this code would be a mess if anyone tried to do it with 3 items at a time. I very much like this solution since it doesn't use temporary variables in an outside scope

Comment: @acidzombie24 if `.push` returned the array instead of the new length the comma operator wouldn't have been necessary

Comment: Well still, TIL I could write `v => (console.log(v), v*2)`. I can't think of a single reason why I would need the array length AFTER adding a value.